# ¿Cómo parametrizar una cadena de conexión en Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Estoy intentando hacer una conexión a MySQL con Entity Framework 6, pero la conexión con la base de datos debe ser dinámica.

¿Cómo puedo parametrizar la cadena de conexión para que al iniciar el programa cargue los modelos de la base de datos ligada?.

Por ejemplo: solicitar al usuario la IP o dominio a conectar, usuario, password y nombre de base de datos, y posteriormente asignárselos al *context* de Entity Framework.

Comment: El modelo lo defines en un edmx o usas Code First ?

Comment: Estoy utilizando edmx

Comment: bien recuerda que el edmx genera codigo en base al diseño visual, como comente vas a tener que extender la funcionalidad del contexto generado, para esto es que se genera una clase partial que permita extender y definir el parametro que indique el connection string. Analiza la respuesta de Dawood en este link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24240761/passing-connection-string-to-entity-framework-6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El constructor de `DbContext` tiene una [sobrecarga donde le puedes pasar la cadena de conexión](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/gg679467):

```
public DbContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
```

Además para armar la cadena de conexión puedes usar la clase `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder` del paquete de nuget [`MySql.Data`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/)

Ejemplo:

```
var builder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    Server = "server",
    UserID = "UserID",
    Password = "Password",
    Database = "Database"
};

var db = new DbContext(builder.ConnectionString);
```

Y si tienes un `DbContext` ya con una clase puedes añadirle el parámetro para recibir la cedena de conexión y pasarsela al constructor de la clase padre:

```
public class EjemploEntities : DbContext
{
    public EjemploEntities(string connectionString)
        :base(connectionString)
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

y luego llamarlo así:

```
var builder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    Server = "server",
    UserID = "UserID",
    Password = "Password",
    Database = "Database"
};
using (var db = new EjemploEntities(builder.ConnectionString))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Este tipo de solución también es válido para SQLite?

Comment: @fedeteka Sí, solo cambia `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder` por `SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

El constructor del DBContext acepta una cadena de conexion, o un nombre de conexion, puedes armar tu conexion con los datos del usuario y pasarlos al constructor

```
public class TuContexto : DbContext
{
    public TuContexto(string connString):base(connString)
    {

    }
```

En el caso de usar Model First, el contexto es generado por una plantilla asi que no puedes modificarlo, pero puedes agregar una clase parcial y usar el mismo metodo

```
public partial class TuContexto
{
    public TuContexto(string connString):base(connString)
    {

    }
}
```

Ejemplo:

```
 string connString="Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";

 TuContexto pre = new TuContexto (connString);
```

[Checa las sobrecargas del constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbContext.%20Sobrecargas%20del%20constructor)

Answer (score 0):

Cuando defines el conecto podrias pasarle un parametro de forma que quede

```
partial class ContextEntities
{
  public ContextEntities( string nombreoConnString )
    : base(nombreoConnString )
  {
  }
}
```

Entonces lo usarias

```
using(ContextEntities db = new ContextEntities("aqui connstring")){
   //codigo
}
```

Esto aplicaria si es Code First, si usas un edmx podrias extender el codigo generado ya que esta se defien como partial, aplicando la misma tecnica que permita indica la cadena de conexion

[Passing Connection String to Entity Framework 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24240761/passing-connection-string-to-entity-framework-6)

Answer (score -1):

```
insert into reg.Tablas (cIdTabla,cDescripcion,cAbrev,cValor) values
('0100','TIPOS DE DOCUMENTO DE INDENTIFICACION','TipoDoc',''),
('0101','DNI','DNI',''),
('0102','PARTIDA DE NACIMIENTO','P. NAC',''),
('0103','PASAPORTE','PASS','')
go

insert into reg.Tablas (cIdTabla,cDescripcion,cAbrev,cValor) values
('0200','ESTADOS CIVILES','EstCiv',''),
('0201','SOLTERO(A)','SOLT',''),
('0202','CASADO(A)','CAS',''),
('0203','VIUDO(A)','VIU',''),
('0204','DIVORCIADO(A)','DIVOR','')
go

insert into reg.Parametros(cIdParametro,cParametro,cValor) values
('IdCliente','Identificador de Clientes','0000000')
go

insert into reg.Agencia(cIdAgencia,cAgencia,cDireccion,dFechaReg) values
('001','OFICINA PRINCIPAL','Plaza de Armas',GETDATE())
go


insert into reg.Tablas (cIdTabla,cDescripcion,cAbrev,cValor) values
('0100','TIPOS DE DOCUMENTO DE INDENTIFICACION','TipoDoc',''),
('0101','DNI','DNI',''),
('0102','PARTIDA DE NACIMIENTO','P. NAC',''),
('0103','PASAPORTE','PASS','')
go

insert into reg.Tablas (cIdTabla,cDescripcion,cAbrev,cValor) values
('0200','ESTADOS CIVILES','EstCiv',''),
('0201','SOLTERO(A)','SOLT',''),
('0202','CASADO(A)','CAS',''),
('0203','VIUDO(A)','VIU',''),
('0204','DIVORCIADO(A)','DIVOR','')
go

insert into reg.Parametros(cIdParametro,cParametro,cValor) values
('IdCliente','Identificador de Clientes','0000000')
go

insert into reg.Agencia(cIdAgencia,cAgencia,cDireccion,dFechaReg) values
('001','OFICINA PRINCIPAL','Plaza de Armas',GETDATE())
go



create procedure reg.SpReg_ListarTabla (@cIdTabla char(4))
as 
begin
    set nocount on

    select cIdTabla, cDescripcion from reg.Tablas where cIdTabla like concat(left(@cIdTabla,2),'%') and cIdTabla <> @cIdTabla
end 
go

create procedure reg.SpReg_DevSecuenciaParametro (@cIdParametro varchar(15), @iTam int)
as 
begin
    set nocount on

    select 'Valor' = right(concat('0000000000',cast(cValor as int) + 1), @iTam) from reg.Parametros where cIdParametro = @cIdParametro
end 
go

create procedure reg.SpReg_GuardarSecuenciaParametro (@cIdParametro varchar(15), @cValor varchar(10))
as 
begin
    update reg.Parametros set cValor=@cValor where cIdParametro = @cIdParametro
end 
go

create procedure reg.SpReg_RegistrarCliente
(
@cIdCliente char(7)
,@cIdTipoDocu   char(4)
,@cNroDocu  varchar(12)
,@cApePat   varchar(45)
,@cApeMat   varchar(45)
,@cNombres  varchar(50)
,@dFechaNac date
,@cSexo char(1)
,@cIdEstCivil   char(4)
,@cDireccion    varchar(80)
,@cTelefono varchar(15)
,@cIdAgencia    char(3)
,@cIdUser   char(6)
)
as 
begin
    insert into reg.Cliente
    (cIdCliente 
    ,cIdTipoDocu    
    ,cNroDocu   
    ,cApePat    
    ,cApeMat    
    ,cNombres   
    ,dFechaNac  
    ,cSexo  
    ,cIdEstCivil    
    ,cDireccion 
    ,cTelefono  
    ,dFechaIngreso  
    ,dFechaReg  
    ,cHoraReg   
    ,cIdAgencia 
    ,cIdUser)
    values
    (@cIdCliente    
    ,@cIdTipoDocu   
    ,@cNroDocu  
    ,@cApePat   
    ,@cApeMat   
    ,@cNombres  
    ,@dFechaNac 
    ,@cSexo 
    ,@cIdEstCivil   
    ,@cDireccion    
    ,@cTelefono 
    ,getdate()  
    ,getdate()
    ,CONVERT(varchar(8),getdate(),108)  
    ,@cIdAgencia    
    ,@cIdUser)

end 
go
```

Comment: por favor explica esta publicación, mira [answer]

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, para responder preguntas en el sitio revisa [answer], es recomendable agregar una explicación del código, que realiza y en que ayuda a resolver la problemática. No olvides realizar el [tour] del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento.